# Images with maximum density

Tags: image

I'm pre-generating a set of web pages, each with a few hundred small, static, randomly sized images.  I would like to fit these images into the smallest area of the page possible.  Order of display isn't particularly important.

Is there a general way to maximize the display density of these images?

Currently, I'm doing the simplest thing possible: gridding the images out in a table.  Not ideal, since it leaves a lot of whitespace.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like the old problem of packing nonuniform rectangles. Exactly what solution you want depends on how close to optimum is "good enough".

Comment: Believe it or not, I last did this problem working a panel saw for a cabinet maker... I'm really open to just about any improvement over tables.

Answer (score 1):

you could just make all of the images floats, that would take up the least amount 'screen real estate.

Comment: This actually works really well for the horizontal packing.  It does leave some room for improvement on the vertical side.  Still, a lot better than what I was doing... thanks!